# Preg_replace in php - multiple replace

Tags: preg-replace

I have $string, which contains:

```
this example
```

and I have these 3 expressions:

```
$pattern = array('/aa*/','/ii*/');
$replacement = array('<i>$0</i>','<b>$0</b>');
preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

where, preg_replace returns:

```
th<b>i</b>s ex<<b>i</b>>a</<b>i</b>>mple
```

and I need output like this:

```
th<b>i</b>s ex<i>a</i>mple
```

which means, that I want to replace only characters in original string. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick in my testing

```
$pattern = array('/([a-z|^|\s])(aa*)/', '/([a-z|^|\s])(ii*)/');
$replacement = array('$1<i>$2</i>','$1<b>$2</b>');
```